# IIS 6 with ASP.NET 4 - what are the disadvantages?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, web-hosting, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking at a hosting company that I plan on going with, but they use IIS 6 with ASP.NET 4.  I plan on running a ASP.NET 4 MVC web application that uses SQL Server (which the hosting company has).

Can I run MVC applications on IIS 6?

Are there any downsides of an ASP.NET MVC Application living on an IIS 6 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I run MVC applications on IIS 6?
Yes

Are there any downsides of an ASP.NET MVC Application living on an IIS 6 server?
No, Your app was built around IIS and .Net integration. IIS6 is Windows Server 2003 based and absolutely up to the task.